# How to access GitHub repo files in a Docker containter created by GitHub action?

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I try to create a custom docker container in GitHub action, but I can't reach my repo files.

I have this `.github/workflows/workflow.yml`:

```yaml
name: Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - my-test-branch

jobs:
  testjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    name: My test job
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: My Custom Action
        uses: ./.github/actions/my-custom-action
```

The `.github/actions/my-custom-action/action.yml` file contains this:

```yaml
name: Docker container test
description: Start container
runs:
  using: docker
  image: ./php.dockerfile
```

In the `.github/actions/my-custom-action/php.dockerfile` contains this:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# here I want to use COPY or ADD to attach the directory to the Docker container
```

I checked GitHub documentation, but nothing was found about this topic. I browsed several Stackoverflow and GitHub issues and tried some tips, but nothing useful.

How can I access repository files from the Docker container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never seen `image: ./php.dockerfile` in a [GitHub Actions workflow file](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-docker-public-registry-action)

You can use a custom image that you have first built and published, for instance to a Docker public registry (like [grc.io](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/)):

```
jobs:
  my_first_job:
    steps:
      - name: My first step
        uses: docker://gcr.io/cloud-builders/gradle
```

But the idea that a GitHub workflow would have to build an image first in order to test your program seems counter-productive.

You can *run* your *existing* custom image, *mounting* (instead of Dockerfile ADD and COPY) checked out folders to your running custom container.
It uses [`jobs.<job_id>.container`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer)

```yaml
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  container-test-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: node:14.16
      env:
        NODE_ENV: development
      ports:
        - 80
      volumes:
        - my_docker_volume:/volume_mount
      options: --cpus 1
    steps:
      - name: Check for dockerenv file
        run: (ls /.dockerenv && echo Found dockerenv) || (echo No dockerenv)
```

You would [mount volumes in a container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-mounting-volumes-in-a-container)

```yaml
Mounting volumes in a container

volumes:
  - my_docker_volume:/volume_mount
  - /data/my_data
  - /source/directory:/destination/directory  <= of interest in your case
```

But all that assumes you *already* built and published your custom image, for your GitHub Action to use at runtime.

Comment: So you say the only way is to create a docker image, publish it to docker hub, then use this published image, right?

Comment: @netdjw Yes, this gist of it is: I don't know if building your custom image during a GitHub action runtime is possible. But using a custom image in your GitHub Action certainly is.